How to find the maximum and minimum values, if any, of $G(x,y)=\frac{\sin(\pi \sqrt{x^2+y^2})}{\pi \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}?$
I have been trying to find the critical points of the function $G(x,y) = \frac{\sin(\pi \sqrt{x^2+y^2})}{\pi \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. The partial derivatives are
$$G_{x}(x,y)=\frac{x}{\pi (x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} \left[\pi \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cos\left(\pi \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)-\sin\left(\pi \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\right]$$
$$G_{y}(x,y)=\frac{y}{\pi (x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} \left[\pi \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cos\left(\pi \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)-\sin\left(\pi \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\right]$$
Now I'm stuck trying to solve these two equations simultaneously
$$x\left[\pi \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cos\left(\pi \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)-\sin\left(\pi \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\right]=0$$
$$y\left[\pi \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cos\left(\pi \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)-\sin\left(\pi \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\right]=0$$
because if $x=0$, then the second equation yields
$$y\left[\pi |y|\cos\left(\pi |y|\right)-\sin\left(\pi |y|\right)\right]=0$$
and I have no idea how to solve it. Any help is appreciated.

Since this function is circularly symmetric, why not just consider $\frac{\sin(\pi r)}{\pi r}$ ?

Indeed, better, consider $\frac{\sin u}u$

Your title says you are interested in maximum and minimum values for this. Are you looking for global extrema, or all local extrema?  Then in the body, you are searching for critical points. Are you doing that because you assume that you need to find critical points to find extrema? Lastly, do you consider this function to be defined at $(x,y)=(0,0)$? If it is not defined there (by declaring a value for it there) then this function has no absolute maximum at all, technically. It has a least upper bound of $1$ that it never attains.

@AndyWalls Could you tell me how I can do that?

@2'59'2 I wanted to search for crtitical points in order to apply the second partial derivative test, so I'm interested in local extrema.

@limber For this function, at places where both partial derivatives are zero, the Hessian matrix will have determinant zero too. For this function, that second derivative test will be inconclusive. This is because the function takes high values and low values in concentric circles, like ripples in a pond after a pebble was thrown in. There are no real isolated peaks. Each "peak" is actually a ring. If you are somewhere on that ring and travel in the direction tangent to that ring, the output does not change quickly enough to have a nonzero second derivative in that direction.

The graph of $z=f(x,y)$ is just the graph of $z=\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$ (in the $xz$-plane) rotated about the $z$-axis. And the graph of $z=\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$ is just a horizontal compression of $z=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. So you can investigate what you are studying by finding the critical points of $z=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. However they are not at locations you can express in some nice way. They are close to $\pm\frac32\pi, \pm\frac52\pi,\ldots$, but not quite those numbers.

@2'59'2 Ok, I get it! Thank you so much for your help.
